# jni can't find the class if the arguments of jvm are converted from other type

Tags: java, c++, qt, jvm, java-native-interface

I have a small-big problem with jni and c++/qt:
This is my code:

```
void Jvm::create_jvm(QStringList &arguments){
    QTextStream cout(stdout);
    JavaVM *jvm;
    JNIEnv *env;
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    JavaVMOption *options[4];
    //run begin
    //options[0].optionString = "-Djava.compiler=NONE";
    //options[1].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=app";
    //options[2].optionString = "-verbose:jni";
    //options[3].optionString = "-Xmx512m";
    //run end

    //can't find the class begin
    QByteArray bArray;
    cout<<"Valores del array arguments"<<endl;
    for(int i;i<arguments.size();i++){

        cout<<arguments.at(i)<<endl;
        bArray=arguments.at(i).toStdString().c_str();
        options[i].optionString = bArray.data();
        cout<<options[i].optionString<<endl;
    }
    //can't find the class end


    //jvm args
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    vm_args.nOptions = 4;
    vm_args.options = options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;


    jint res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
    if (res < 0) {//jvm don't created
        qDebug()<<"Can't create Java VM\n";
        exit(1);
    }else{//jvm created
        invoke_class(env);
        jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
    }
}

void Jvm::invoke_class(JNIEnv* env) {
    jclass cls;
    jmethodID mainMethod;
    jobjectArray applicationArgs;
    jstring applicationArg0,applicationArg1,applicationArg2;

    //class and main method
    cls = env->FindClass("HolaMundoSwing");
    if (cls == 0) qDebug()<<"Sorry, I can't find the class"; //In case that class not exist
    mainMethod = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");

    //Application arguments array
    applicationArgs = env->NewObjectArray(3, env->FindClass("java/lang/String"), NULL);
    applicationArg0 = env->NewStringUTF("From");
    applicationArg1 = env->NewStringUTF("C");
    applicationArg2 = env->NewStringUTF("program");

    env->SetObjectArrayElement(applicationArgs, 0, applicationArg0);
    env->SetObjectArrayElement(applicationArgs, 1, applicationArg1);
    env->SetObjectArrayElement(applicationArgs, 2, applicationArg2);

    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, mainMethod, applicationArgs); //Call to the method
}
```

I have tested the arguments and are the same.
The classpath have the same value, but the commented code run correctly and the other code can't find the class, any idea?

Comment: What's your question? It is not clear to me where you have a problem.

Comment: What does "I have tested the arguments and are the same" mean? What does "classpath have same value" mean? Same as what? What is the "commented code", and the "other code"? What on earth is this question about?

Answer (score 0):

Your for-loop contains an error:

```
for( int i; i < arguments.size(); i++ )
```

should be

```
for( int i = 0; i < arguments.size(); i++ )
```

Otherwise `i` will have any random start value (at least with my compiler)